# How to find the duplicate entries of an array of string and make them null by using HashMap

Tags: java, collections

I've an array of string, I want to find the duplicate strings in the array and want to make the duplicates null by using HashMap with a good time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a Set.  This clears all duplicate entries, but you can also just create an array which has the unique entries (and no null values)

```
String[] array =
Set<String> found = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
   if(!found.add(array[i]))
       array[i] = null;

// just the entries without duplicates.
String[] unique = found.toArray(new String[found.size()]);
```

Comment: @aioobe. To keep the order when he gets the unique values from the set.

Comment: So the order is retained in the array. i.e. if there are no duplicates, unique would be the same as array.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear that he actually wants to get hold of the duplicates, but I guess that's a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a map. Here's an example that uses a `HashSet` instead. (Assuming that you want the repeated strings "nulled" out.

```
String[] strs = "aa,bb,cc,aa,xx,cc,dd".split(",");

Set<String> seen = new HashSet<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++)
    if (!seen.add(strs[i]))
        strs[i] = null;

// Prints [aa, bb, cc, null, xx, null, dd]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in `O(n)` time, by iterating over your array once, sticking every new element into a `HashSet` and replacing array elements that are already in the `HashSet` with `nulls`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a HashMap you can use a Set too, the steps are (you can work the details out yourself):

- for every string in the array
- if the string exists in the Map/Set null it
- otherwise add it to the Map/Set

That's it.